# How to redirect document root via htaccess and block direct access to the new document root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have created `.htaccess` rules, which work pretty fine, they redirect the user to the new document root but I can still access the contents of the website by just simply typing the name of the new document root in the address bar, this is something that is not desired

`example.com` - shows contents of www

but

`example.com/www` and `example.com/www/` - work as well and this is something I want to change (show 404 instead)

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/www` subdirectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (show 404 instead)

You might as well just redirect the user to the correct/canonical URL instead. (See the additional note at the end of this answer if you still want to trigger a 404 instead.)

If you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/www` subdirectory that already contains mod_rewrite directives then add the following at the top of the `/www/.htaccess` file:

```
# /www/.htaccess    

# Redirect direct requests back to the root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE:** The *trick* here is the use of the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable in order to detect direct requests from the client/browser and not internally rewritten requests by the parent `.htaccess` file. On the initial request the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is *empty*, but after the first successful rewrite it is set to the string `200` (as in "200 OK" HTTP status).

Whilst the above rule might at first look as if it redirects to itself - it does not. Since the rule is in the `/www` subdirectory, the regex `(.*)` only captures the part of the URL that occurs *after* `/www/` in the URL-path.

**OR**

Otherwise, if you only have the `.htaccess` file in the document root then add the following *before* the existing rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
# /.htaccess    

# Redirect direct requests to the "/www" directory back to the root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^www(?:$|/(.*)) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The regex `^www(?:$|/(.*))` matches either `www` only or `www/<anything>` and redirects back to `/<anything>`, removing the `/www/` prefix.

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

---

#### To return a 404 instead

If, however, you would rather trigger a 404 Not Found response instead, then change the `RewriteRule` directive in the above to the following:

```
:
RewriteRule <pattern> - [R=404]
```

Where `<pattern>` is the first argument (from the two rules above) to the respective `RewriteRule` directive.

Comment: both solutions are great
works like a charm
thank you!

Comment: @losingfire You're welcome. I realise I didn't explain the use of `REDIRECT_STATUS`... I've updated my answer.